# IWebHost.Build() is not calling Startup.Configure() after upgrading to .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been working on a site in .Net Core 2.0 for several months. I just upgraded to .Net Core 2.1 and now the `Startup.Configure()` method is not being called.

I have the following code in my `Program` class, which creates the `IWebHost`:

```
    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(LoadAppConfiguration)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

Until I upgraded the framework, this was working perfectly, instantiating `Startup` and correctly calling the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods.

Now, although `Startup` is being instantiated, `Configure` is no longer being called. (No exceptions are being thrown.)

I realise there is a lot of other code in my application start up. But the only thing that I have done is to update the .Net Core SDK from 2.0 to 2.1.

Perhaps someone has an idea what might have changed or what I can investigate?

Comment: See if [The Startup class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-startup-class) helps any.

Comment: Can you see anything in your output window? Maybe you should post your startup class as well

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the startup sequence has changed since .Net Core 2.0. I have not found any documentation or discussion on GitHub to confirm this, but my own testing has been clear.

It used to be that `Startup.Configure` got called by `WebHostBuilder.Build()`. But this call is now deferred to `WebHost.Run()` [or `WebHost.Start()` if you are using that].

I managed to get around it by injecting `IApplicationLifetime` and registering a callback to perform my database migration etc. For what it is worth, I think the startup sequence is quite convoluted now and it would be nice to have a few simpler hooks to run code at the necessary points.

Thanks to everyone that commented or offered suggestions.

Comment: OMG thank you! I was just pulling my hairs out with this exact problem (going from 2.0 => 2.2 though). Lovely how MS makes breaking changes in minor releases... It is worth noting  that `IApplicationLifetime ` has been deprecated in favor of `IHostApplicationLifetime`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: seems that `ConfigureAppConfiguration` replaces `Startup` if used in the web host builder (as it is used in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-services-without-startup) ). So I've moved the `LoadAppConfiguration` call to the `Startup.Startup` were `ConfigurationBuilder` is created. It was possible since I did not used the `context`.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was to just restart visual studio.